# String wildcard in pandas on replace function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this problem has an easy answer but I'm having trouble figuring out the correct string to use. I basically want to replace any email address in a data frame with the new domain. For a specific column, replace the substring '@*' where * is any set of characters with '@newcompany.com'. I want to keep whatever comes prior to the @ as is.
Thanks all.

```
df_users['EMAIL'] = df_users['EMAIL'].str.replace('@', '@newcompany.com')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method to split on `'@'` character and then join the left side with the new domain name:

```
In [42]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'email':['asdsad@old.com', 'asdsa@google.com', 'hheherhe@apple.com']})
df
Out[42]:
                email
0      asdsad@old.com
1    asdsa@google.com
2  hheherhe@apple.com

In [43]:

df['email'] = df.email.str.split('@').str[0] + '@newcompany.com'
df

Out[43]:
                     email
0    asdsad@newcompany.com
1     asdsa@newcompany.com
2  hheherhe@newcompany.com
```

another method is to call the vectorised `replace` which accepts a regex as a pattern on the strings:

```
In [56]:

df['email'] = df['email'].str.replace(r'@.+', '@newcompany.com')
df
Out[56]:
                     email
0    asdsad@newcompany.com
1     asdsa@newcompany.com
2  hheherhe@newcompany.com
```

**Timings**

```
In [58]:

%timeit df['email'] = df['email'].str.replace(r'@.+', '@newcompany.com')
1000 loops, best of 3: 632 µs per loop
In [60]:

%timeit df['email'] = df.email.str.split('@').str[0] + '@newcompany.com'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 ms per loop

In [63]:

%timeit df['email'] = df['email'].replace(r'@.+', '@newcompany.com', regex=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 738 µs per loop
```

Here we can see that the `str.replace` regex version is nearly 3x faster than the `split` method, interestingly the [Series.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas.Series.replace) method which would seem to be doing the same thing as the `str.replace` is slower.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for [regex](https://xkcd.com/208/)! Pandas' `replace` will let you use regular expressions, you just have to set it to true. You're most of the way there, the following should work for you.

`df_users['EMAIL'].replace('@.*$', '@newcompany.com', inplace=True, regex=True)`